# Measuring within-group similarity for ranked list responses

Tags: ranking, group-differences, similarities, agreement-statistics

Individuals are completing a task in which they rank 15 items (1-15 according to importance). These individuals will later be working in groups of 4, so I am interested in measuring the similarity of responses within each group.
Any recommendations on measurement techniques that would best capture this similarity?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you probably want some measure of the dissimilarity of two rankings. My first thought would be the [Kendall Tau Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_distance) which will give you an integer between 0 and 105 with 0 indicating the two rankings are identical and 105 indicating that one ranking is the exact reverse of the other.

Then you would need some way of aggregating that up to groups of four. The simplest would be to compute all pairwise Kendall Tau Distances and take an average.

Both of these steps are subject to debate. For example, the Kendall Tau Distance counts only when two rankings are in disagreement with each other and does not measure how badly they disagree. Other measures such as simple correlation are also available.

There are also other ways of aggregating among the four members of each group. You could take the maximum dissimilarity among all pairwise comparisons. Or you might compute a new groupwise ranking which minimizes the maximum dissimilarity between it and each member of the group. But honestly, a simple average is probably fine.